# EF 6 MVC 5 Invalid Column Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After reverse engineering a Database, to generate the models/mapping/dbcontext all is well until I actually add something. Here are my models.

```
public partial class Vendor
{
    public Vendor()
    {
        this.VendorToSuppliesAndServices = new List<VendorToSuppliesAndService>();
    }

    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VendorToSuppliesAndService> VendorToSuppliesAndServices { get; set; }

}
```

The VendorToSuppliesAndService

```
    public partial class VendorToSuppliesAndService
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
        public int VendorID { get; set; }
        public string OtherInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

And Here is the VendorToSuppliesAndServiceMap Constructor

```
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.OtherInfo)
            .HasMaxLength(1300);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("VendorToSuppliesAndServices");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.VendorID).HasColumnName("VendorID");
        this.Property(t => t.OtherInfo).HasColumnName("OtherInfo");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Vendor)
            .WithMany(t => t.VendorToSuppliesAndServices)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.VendorID);
```

Now the problem is when I do an addition.

```
   Vendor vendor = ....
   VendorToSuppliesAndService service = ....
   vendor.VendorToSuppliesAndServices.add(service);
   context.Vendors.Add(vendor);
   context.SaveChanges();
```

That's the problem, it should be noted that without

```
   VendorToSuppliesAndService service = ....
   vendor.VendorToSuppliesAndServices.add(service);
```

The problem goes away.

Here's the stacktrack:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Vendor_VendorID'.]
          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
```

Comment: If you had an existing database, why did you go through the effort of doing a code-first solution?

Comment: I did nothing but Right Click > Entity Framework > Build Models

Comment: I would generate an edmx and see if the problem is in the code generation or the database or code.

Comment: Can you post the two database tables

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem the other day! Almost forgot to update it here.I couldn't tell you exactly why, but the "**ICollection**" class was the issue. By changing it to a **IList** container all my problems melted away. Now I would love if someone could explain why this worked, as it was a hail mary on my part.

Thanks again for the help guys.